# Difference between Mishlei 11:13 and 20:19

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, mishlei

[Mishlei (proverbs) 11:13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Proverbs.11.13?lang=bi):

**הוֹלֵ֣ךְ רָ֭כִיל מְגַלֶּה־סּ֑וֹד** וְנֶאֱמַן־ר֝֗וּחַ מְכַסֶּ֥ה דָבָֽר׃

**A base fellow gives away secrets**, But a trustworthy soul keeps a confidence.

[Mishlei (proverbs) 20:19](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Proverbs.20.19?lang=bi):

**גּֽוֹלֶה־סּ֭וֹד הוֹלֵ֣ךְ רָכִ֑יל** וּלְפֹתֶ֥ה שְׂ֝פָתָ֗יו לֹ֣א תִתְעָרָֽב׃

**He who gives away secrets is a base fellow**; Do not take up with a garrulous man.

Do the first segments of these two pesukim mean the same thing?

If they do, why the repetition?

Suggestion: The first pasuk is telling us about "A base fellow". It tells us that one who is known to be a base person "gives away secrets". So don't trust him with your secrets.

The second pasuk is telling us about a person who gives away secrets, and it tells us that he is a base man, and thus, one should not take up with a such a garrulous man.

Related: [Mishlei 11:13 and 20:19 Same beginning different Endings](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93682/mishlei-1113-and-2019-same-beginning-different-endings)

Comment: Related: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/33416/are-exodus-238-and-deuteronmy-1619-meant-to-be-identical

Comment: Simply from a logic standpoint, they don’t mean the same thing. And the translation of הולך רכיל leaves much to be desired. Garrulous means talkative and rambling in conversation. That isn’t the same idea as a purveyor of gossip (רכילות).

Comment: @YaacovDeane I was only asking about the first part of each passuk not the end. So discussing "Garrulous" seems irrelevant to my question. Do you mean to  differentiate between the 2 psukim with what you commented? [see my edited additions to the question].

Comment: See also this article from Nachum Rakover: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/shana/rakover-1.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Malbim here suggests a similar solution, namely that the first Passuk suggests that one who peddles will naturally reveal secrets, and the second passuk is saying that if someone is known to reveal secrets, they likely peddle these things around:

> הולך רכיל מגלה סוד, באר שמי שהולך רכיל טבעו לגלות סוד של חברו, והסוד הוא כפקדון שחברו מפקיד אצל רוחו, וכמו שלא יפקיד אדם פקדון אצל בלתי נאמן, כי אין להפקיד סוד אל רוח הבלתי נאמן, וכשהולך רכיל ידע שהוא גם בלתי נאמן ברוחו, ולקמן אמר גולה סוד הולך רכיל, באר שכן גם בהפך אם נראה איש מגלה סוד נדע שטבעו להיות הולך רכיל, ונאמן רוח מכסה דבר, שלא לבד שאינו מגלה סוד הוא משתדל לכסות את הדבר ולהעלימו, וכ"ש שלא ילך רכיל לגלות ולפרסם עניני חבירו:

Comment: Thank you for citing the  גאון ישראל קודש הקדשים רבינו הגדול המלבים זכר צדיק וקדוש לברכה.